# Android Device Chooser detects my Galaxy S4 as "unknown"

Tags: android, debugging, usb

Why does it happen? I already have switched USB debugging on. Kies is installed (in case that Win Update won't find the usb drivers). For any ideas I appreciate everyone!

[image]

Comment: My Galaxy Tab is touchy too. Try exiting Eclipse, plug in your S4 and then start Eclipse. The Tab has to be started just the right way or its not happy.

Answer (score 3):

The reason for this behaviour is device is unauthorised  for USB debugging. Ideally a pop up should appear on the device asking to provide permission for USB debugging. Select Allow always for this computer and click OK. This will solve the offline issue.

If the pop up does not come up when you plug the device to computer. Open adb command prompt and run

**adb usb** in command prompt(with device connected to computer through USB) this will reboot android adb usb listner which will force the pop up to come on the device.

Answer (score 2):

Your device state is shown as offline. Check your device for a message requesting permission to debug.

http://www.wugfresh.com/faqs/how-to-fix-adb-device-is-listed-as-offline-on-android-4-2-2/

Comment: Link dead. I know I have to give permission for each computer but for some reason it doesn't show up sometimes. Can you edit your answer with another link or explain how to see the permission popup window?

Answer (score 2):

Check that you have latest Android SDK tools. After installing latest SDK tools, check your phone: you need to confirm that you allow debugging from your computer.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the [Samsung Mobile Innovator site](http://developer.samsung.com/android/tools-sdks/Samsung-Andorid-USB-Driver-for-Windows) and a "Download: SAMSUNG_USB_Driver_for_Mobile_Phones.exe". Install it.

This simply worked for me for both the Galaxy-Tab and the Epic.